# End a function (with return) after an event is triggered.

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, web

is there any way to end a function after an event is triggered? Actually i'm trying to merge my html files into one html and i want to stop the script from the previous page from running while i'm not on that page.The problem is that i have a setInterval running on my script so the "next page" transition is triggered multiple times even after i declared variables for avoiding multiple execution of commands,it looks like the same page on my browser runs in parallel multiple times.

Comment: Can you include the code in your question please?

Comment: Use a global variable and keep checking if its set to a certain value. If it is, use the `return` statement to get out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question: "Is there any way to end a function after an event is triggered?"
    - A function likely is not running in parallel, if you need it to exit have it check a flag variable in an outer scope.

To solve what I believe is your problem: "I have setInterval running on my script, transition is triggered multiple times"
    - The setInterval method returns a handle that you can use to clear the interval with window.clearInterval()

Comment: I've tried clearInterval and control variables and the problem remains.I stored the number of times that a click is pressed on a button.Since i push it one time my browser should alerted "1" but after 3 visits on the page i get three alerts (although i made it impossible to alert more than once and nulled the count variable after i exit the page).So i got, "3", "2", "1".

Comment: It turned out that every time i revesed a page the buttons were attached to the event one extra time so when i pushed a button multiple events tirggered silmultaniously.I fixed it by unbinding the buttons like this   $(document).off('click', '#test-button').on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });